# How i can optimizating my code in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try optimizating my games, how i can optimizating my random generator?

PS: Game have occulison culling, dynamic batching, no rich text, GPU Instancing, LOD Groups on best population object (Berries, Logs, Leaves on tree, stick).

```
using static System.Random;
using UnityEngine;

public class StickGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Игровые объекты")] // game objects
    public GameObject Object;

    [Header("Лимит строений")] // is builded?
    private bool objectBuilded = false;

    [Header("Количество")] // how much
    public int what;

    [Header("Максимум блоков для рендера")] // max X and Z for render
    public int maxRangeX;
    public int maxRangeZ;

    [Header("Рандомные координаты")] // random coordinations
    private int randomPosX;
    private int randomPosZ;

    private void Start() // generation
    {
        if(objectBuilded == false)
        {
            System.Random randomPos = new System.Random();

            for (int i = 0; i <= what; i++)
            {
                randomPosX = randomPos.Next(1, maxRangeX);
                randomPosZ = randomPos.Next(1, maxRangeZ);

                Instantiate(Object, new Vector3(randomPosX, 0.56f, randomPosZ), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            objectBuilded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Please check what type of questions you should ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
and what questions you avoid asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: You can avoid instantiating all the time. You can instantiate for example 100 of your objects, and if they die don't destroy them, but put somewhere very far from the scene. When you need to spawn a new object, you just set new coordinates to an existing object

Comment: This is also called [pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling#5ff8d015edbc2a002063971d)

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging with the profiler to see what kind of spikes you are getting, that way you can now where to optimize first.